# Importing bmp file in C++

Tags: c++, image, import

I have looked at numerous tutorials but I just can't make the Pixel data reading work...

Here is what I have got so far:

```
struct RGB
{
 unsigned char blue,green,red,reserved;
};

BmpLoader* loadBmp(const char* filename)
{
BITMAPFILEHEADER header;
BITMAPINFOHEADER info;
FILE *file;
file=fopen(filename,"rb");

fread(&header,sizeof(header),1,file);
fread(&info,sizeof(info),1,file);
unsigned char *px;
int bitsize=info.biWidth*info.biHeight;
px=new unsigned char[bitsize*3];
fseek(file,header.bfOffBits,0);
for(int i=0;i<bitsize;i++)
{
    RGB rgb;
    fread(&rgb,sizeof(RGB),1,file);
    px[i*3]=rgb.red;
    px[i*3+1]=rgb.green;
    px[i*3+2]=rgb.blue;
    printf("%d %d %d\n",px[i*3],px[i*3+1],px[i*3+2]);

}

    return new BmpLoader(px,info.biWidth,info.biHeight);

}
```

As you can see I have also tried to print them as decimals which should have given the ascii code of the characters and the output looks like this :

```
204 204 76
204 204 255
204 204 136
204 204 76
204 204 255
204 204 136
```

My question is : How can I fix this? What am I exactly doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only reading one byte into `rgb`

```
fread(&rgb,1,1,file);
```

should be

```
fread(&rgb,sizeof(RGB),1,file);
```

Comment: Ah, fixed that part but the same ending resault... only now it displays : 136 255 76 instead of the things above ( also there were some other variations but overall instead of displaying the bmp it displays the color pink ). P.S. I am sure the picture is correct and the way of displaying it

Comment: Hard to say, it's a long time since I wrote any code like this. However you are making any number of assumptions about the format of your bitmap. For instance you are assuming that `info.biBitCount  == 24` and more seriously you are assuming there is no padding between your lines. Each line of the image will be padded to a multiple of four bytes, so unless your width is a multiple of four your code isn't going to work.

Comment: I made this assumtions based on the fact that I made the picture.It is a 256x256 picture and it is 24 byte bmp.

Comment: Are you sure your RGB structure is correct? Was that even there before, I don't remember seeing it. I've just done my own testing with using your code on a 24-bit 256 x 256 pixel bitmap. For the bitmap I used you should delete the `reserved` member from your RGB structure, i.e. sizeof(RGB) should be 3 not 4. But your bitmap might be different.